# change website for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I have website and i would like change style to mobile friendly (big buttons, big text fields etc). How can i do this?
html file:

```
<link href="jquery-ui/css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

And css file:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1366px)  {

 .name { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color:#369; font-size:50px; text-align:right; width:600px;}

}
```

And nothing happens website looks same on screen and on tablet

Comment: that style will only be applied to screens larger than 768px

Comment: Make sure to add the viewport meta element as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the exact pixel dimensions of the device you are trying to create the separate styles for. To get the styles into the right range.

The best page I've found for this is on CSS Tricks, it lists all of the most common media queries used in CSS. I think you'll find everything you need there! :)

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/